# Pug interpolation for JSON

Tags: pug, interpolation, json-ld, string-interpolation, pugjs

Pug deprecated interpolation. But gulp-pug does not deal with ES6 template strings. Can somebody help with JSON-LD in pug. What shoud be right alternative for this?

```
script(type="application/ld+json").
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@id": "#{site.home}/#organization",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "#{company.name}",
    "description": "#{company.businessDescription}"
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure pug deprecated interpolation? https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html

Comment: What is the problem with the code in your post?